# Count cummulative distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have the below table. Is it possible to do a cummulative distinct count? For example, if A1 has 3 distinct values, then the count for it will be 3. Afterwards, check for A1 and A2. If A1 and A2 together have 5 distinct values, 5. Repeat until A1 + A2 ... + An and count the distinct values.

| A | V |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | V1 |
| A1 | V2 |
| A1 | V2 |
| A2 | V1 |
| A2 | V2 |
| A2 | V3 |

My expected output would be:

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 |
| A2 | 3 |

Comment: Do you mean "cumulative" or do you in fact mean "incremental"? Can you explain exactly what you mean, without using a single word like "cumulative"?

Comment: Also, can `V` be null? And if it can, how should it be handled? Normally `null` is not "counted" in SQL.

Comment: If there are 3 distinct values in A1 but only 2 of them exist for A2, it should be 3 for A3 and 2 for A2.

Comment: @mathguy if V is null, then it should not be counted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a detailed explanation of the logic as "cumulative distinct count" is not self-explanatory. It may also be necessary to provide multiple result sets and describe the expected output for each. Also answering: "in your question `A2` has 3 distinct values but has a count of 1, why?" or "in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547062/count-cummulative-distinct#comment119393247_67547062) you say `A1` has 3 distinct values then the count should be 3 but in your question `A2` has 3 distinct values and the expected count is 1; why this difference?"

Comment: @MT0 question amended with explanation.

Comment: @jeiv Your edit does not match [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547062/count-cummulative-distinct?noredirect=1#comment119393247_67547062) as surely if there are 3 distinct values in A1 but only 2 of them exist for A2, it should be 3 for A1 (I am assuming that As is a typo) and then 3 for A1 + A2 and so the cumulative count for A2 will remain at 3 (rather than dropping to 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to find the 1st occurrence of each `V` and then `COUNT()` window function to count only these 1st occurrences:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY A) C
FROM (
  SELECT A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V ORDER BY A) rn
  FROM tablename 
) t
ORDER BY A
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f5f4209920f2c7620e14244042e5ff3).

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can aggregate twice . . . once to keep the *first* occurrence of `v` and the second to aggregate again:

```
select a, count(*) as new_cs
from (select v, min(a) as a
      from t
      group by v
     ) v
group by a;
```

Note:  The above only shows `a`s that have new values.  If you want all `a`, then window functions are a better approach:

```
select a, sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as c
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by v order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by a
order by a;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e5cee0682f52c6eb15a975ee4ece0f5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: But the below does not work if I change the V in row 3 to V3.

Comment: @jeiv . . . I produces the results that I would expect based on your question.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I've amended the question with a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [partitioned outer join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227069/) to ensure that all `V` values are counted for all `A` values and then use the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function to find whether a value exists in the current or preceding `A` values for the `V`:

```sql
SELECT a,
       COUNT( DISTINCT fv ) AS c
FROM   (
  SELECT t.a,
         FIRST_VALUE(t.v) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY v.v
           ORDER BY t.a
           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
         ) AS fv
  FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT v FROM table_name ) v
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY ( t.a )
         ON ( t.v = v.v )
)
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, V ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'V1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'V2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'V3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'V1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'V3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'V4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'V2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'V3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 'V1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 'V5' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | A | C |
> | --- | --- |
> | A1 | 3 |
> | A2 | 4 |
> | A3 | 4 |
> | A4 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da964d5ff4cd68468996aa686d5948b1)*